# Points which has the same date are placed to the different places at X-axis (X-axis is a date axis)

Tags: javascript, php, amcharts

**The problem:**

Points which has the same date are placed to the different places at X-axis (X-axis is a date axis).

http://icecream.me/b8388ef9e8d80e3a55dc546cd61187d9

**Here are AmCharts settings:**

```
                            AmCharts.makeChart("dashboard-chart", {
                                "type": "serial",
                                "theme": "light",
                                "equalSpacing": true,
                                "dataProvider": chartData,
                                "valueAxes": valueAxes,
                                "graphs": graphs,
                                "categoryField": "captured_datetime",
                                'chartCursor': {
                                    'cursorPosition': 'mouse',
                                    'cursorColor': '#ffa500',
                                    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
                                    "valueLineEnabled": true,
                                },
                                "categoryAxis": {
                                    "gridPosition": "middle",
                                    "labelRotation": 75,
                                    "minorGridEnabled": true

                                },
                                "responsive": {
                                    "enabled": true
                                }
                            });
```

**Incoming data looks like this:**

```
[  
   {  
      "node_id":"1680",
      "node_name":"Internal",
      "nd":"1",
      "sensor_type":"TM",
      "captured_datetime":"2018-02-01 19:31:33",
      "valueTM1680":"91.1"
   },
   {  
      "node_id":"1680",
      "node_name":"Internal",
      "nd":"1",
      "sensor_type":"HU",
      "captured_datetime":"2018-02-01 19:31:33",
      "valueHU1680":"72.6"
   },
   {  
      "node_id":"1680",
      "node_name":"Internal",
      "nd":"1",
      "sensor_type":"TM",
      "captured_datetime":"2018-02-01 19:33:13",
      "valueTM1680":"91.1"
   },
   {  
      "node_id":"1680",
      "node_name":"Internal",
      "nd":"1",
      "sensor_type":"HU",
      "captured_datetime":"2018-02-01 19:33:13",
      "valueHU1680":"72.6"
   }
]
```

**Graph example:**

```
graphs.push({
                                            "balloonText": "Sensor name: [[node_name]] <br> Sensor id: [[nd]] <br> Sensor value:[[value]]<br> Sensor type: [[sensor_type]]<br>  Collecting date: [[captured_datetime]] <br>",
                                            "bullet": "round",
                                            "lineColor": "#000000",
                                            "bulletSize": 3,
                                            "fillAlphas": types[i].indexOf("TM") >= 0 ? 1 : 0,
                                            "type": types[i].indexOf("TM") >= 0 ? "column" : "smoothedLine",
                                            "labelPosition": "right",
                                            "valueField": "value" + types[i],
                                            "fixedColumnWidth": 10
                                        })
```

**Tried to use parseDates with following parameters (*but it didn`t help*):**

```
 "minPeriod":"ss",
"parseDates":true
```

**Added following settings to a chart (which didn`t helped either):**

```
"dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS", "equalSpacing": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have to group your data as I mentioned in my [last answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48581473/6106614). The issue you're seeing there is what I meant by other odd behavior. If you can't group your data in your backend, then do it in JavaScript. You also need to make sure that your dates are sorted in ascending order:

```
// data remap:
var datetime_hash = {};
var types = {};
data.forEach(function(item, idx) {
    if (!datetime_hash.hasOwnProperty(item.captured_datetime)) {
        datetime_hash[item.captured_datetime] = {};
    }
    var suffix = item.sensor_type + item.node_id;
    types[suffix] = 1;
    datetime_hash[item.captured_datetime]["sensor_type" + suffix] = item.sensor_type;
    datetime_hash[item.captured_datetime]["node_name"] = item.node_name;
    datetime_hash[item.captured_datetime]["node_id"] = item.node_id;
    datetime_hash[item.captured_datetime]["nd"] = item.nd;
    datetime_hash[item.captured_datetime]["value" + suffix] = item["value" + suffix];
    datetime_hash[item.captured_datetime]["captured_datetime"] = item.captured_datetime;
})
//sort/remap hash data into an array
var chartData = Object.keys(datetime_hash).sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
  //ensure the dates are sorted in ascending order
  var lhsDate = AmCharts.stringToDate(lhs, "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS");
  var rhsDate = AmCharts.stringToDate(rhs, "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS");
  return lhsDate - rhsDate;
}).map(function(datetime) {
  return datetime_hash[datetime];
});

// updated graph creation code:
types = Object.keys(types);
var graphs = types.map(function(type) {
    return {
            "balloonText": "Sensor name: [[node_name]] <br> Sensor id: [[nd]] <br> Sensor value:[[value]]<br> Sensor type: [[sensor_type" + type + "]]<br>  Collecting date: [[captured_datetime]] <br>",
            "bullet": "round",
            "lineColor": "#000000",
            "bulletSize": 3,
            "fillAlphas": type.indexOf("TM") >= 0 ? 1 : 0,
            "type": type.indexOf("TM") >= 0 ? "column" : "smoothedLine",
            "labelPosition": "right",
            "valueField": "value" + type,
            "fixedColumnWidth": 10
    }
});
```

In case you want to parse dates (and you should), you have to set the dataDateFormat at the top level of the makeChart call and `equalSpacing`, `minPeriod`, `parseDates` inside the `categoryAxis`.

Demo with additional dummy data:

```js
var data = [{
    "valueTM1680": 24.9,
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "TM",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "HU",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "valueHU1680": 39.9,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "valueTM1680": 22.3,
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "TM",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:00:05"
  },
  {
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "HU",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "valueHU1680": 37.8,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:00:05"
  },
  {
    "valueTM1680": 20.1,
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "TM",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:00:24"
  },
  {
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "HU",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "valueHU1680": 36.0,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:00:24"
  },
  {
    "valueTM1680": 24.8,
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "TM",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:00:43"
  },
  {
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "HU",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "valueHU1680": 38.8,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:00:43"
  },
  {
    "valueTM1680": 24.7,
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "TM",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:00:57"
  },
  {
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "HU",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "valueHU1680": 38.8,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:00:57"
  },
  {
    "valueTM1680": 24.7,
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "TM",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:01:07"
  },
  {
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "HU",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "valueHU1680": 37.9,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:01:07"
  },
  {
    "valueTM1680": 24.6,
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "TM",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:01:21"
  },
  {
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "HU",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "valueHU1680": 37.3,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:01:21"
  },
  {
    "valueTM1680": 23.8,
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "TM",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:01:34"
  },
  {
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "HU",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "valueHU1680": 36.4,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:01:34"
  },
  {
    "valueTM1680": 20.3,
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "TM",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:01:47"
  },
  {
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "HU",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "valueHU1680": 37.9,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:01:47"
  },
  {
    "valueTM1680": 21.8,
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "TM",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:02:01"
  },
  {
    "nd": 1,
    "node_name": "Internal",
    "sensor_type": "HU",
    "node_id": 1680,
    "valueHU1680": 37.3,
    "captured_datetime": "2018-01-01 00:02:01"
  }
]



//remap data
var datetime_hash = {};
var types = {};

data.forEach(function(item, idx) {
  if (!datetime_hash.hasOwnProperty(item.captured_datetime)) {
    datetime_hash[item.captured_datetime] = {};
  }
  var suffix = item.sensor_type + item.node_id;
  types[suffix] = 1;
  datetime_hash[item.captured_datetime]["sensor_type" + suffix] = item.sensor_type;
  datetime_hash[item.captured_datetime]["node_name"] = item.node_name;
  datetime_hash[item.captured_datetime]["node_id"] = item.node_id;
  datetime_hash[item.captured_datetime]["nd"] = item.nd;
  datetime_hash[item.captured_datetime]["value" + suffix] = item["value" + suffix];
  datetime_hash[item.captured_datetime]["captured_datetime"] = item.captured_datetime;
});
//sort/remap hash data into an array
var chartData = Object.keys(datetime_hash).sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
  //ensure the dates are sorted in ascending order
  var lhsDate = AmCharts.stringToDate(lhs, "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS");
  var rhsDate = AmCharts.stringToDate(rhs, "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS");
  return lhsDate - rhsDate;
}).map(function(datetime) {
  return datetime_hash[datetime];
});

//create graphs
types = Object.keys(types);
var graphs = types.map(function(type) {
  return {
    "balloonText": "Sensor name: [[node_name]] <br> Sensor id: [[nd]] <br> Sensor value:[[value]]<br> Sensor type: [[sensor_type" + type + "]]<br>  Collecting date: [[captured_datetime]] <br>",
    "bullet": "round",
    //"lineColor": "#000000",
    "bulletSize": 3,
    "fillAlphas": type.indexOf("TM") >= 0 ? 1 : 0,
    "type": type.indexOf("TM") >= 0 ? "column" : "smoothedLine",
    "labelPosition": "right",
    "valueField": "value" + type,
    "fixedColumnWidth": 10
  }
});


AmCharts.makeChart("dashboard-chart", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  //"equalSpacing": true, this is a categoryAxis property.
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  //"valueAxes": valueAxes,
  "graphs": graphs,
  "categoryField": "captured_datetime",
  'chartCursor': {
    'cursorPosition': 'mouse',
    'cursorColor': '#ffa500',
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
  },
  "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN:SS",
  "categoryAxis": {
    //"gridPosition": "middle",
    "labelRotation": 75,
    "minorGridEnabled": true,
    "parseDates": true,
    "minPeriod": "ss",
    //customize axis:
    "markPeriodChange": false,
    "dateFormats": [{
      "period": "fff",
      "format": "JJ:NN:SS"
    }, {
      "period": "ss",
      "format": "YYYY-MM-DD\nJJ:NN:SS"
    }, {
      "period": "mm",
      "format": "JJ:NN"
    }, {
      "period": "hh",
      "format": "JJ:NN"
    }, {
      "period": "DD",
      "format": "MMM DD"
    }, {
      "period": "WW",
      "format": "MMM DD"
    }, {
      "period": "MM",
      "format": "MMM"
    }, {
      "period": "YYYY",
      "format": "YYYY"
    }]

  },
  "responsive": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#dashboard-chart {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard-chart"></div>
```